# Django runserver fails without any error message

Tags: django

I have been working a project using python3 and django. I'm using the debian environment. The problem is python3 manage.py runserver provides the following output.

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Using TensorFlow backend.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

[I get this in terminal. No error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iLj1.png)